# React Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render. when using useState and map

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have React code which fetch from my Api posts and displays it.

when I tried to display the posts with `map`, I used `useState` inside the `map` and I got this error:

`Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`

When I deleted the useState it worked.

This is my code

```
import {useState,useContext,useEffect} from "react"
import {username} from "./username"

const PostDisplay = (post) => {

  const [try, setTry] = useState("")

  return (
    <div>Hello</div>
  );


}


function Home(){

    const [loggedIn,setLoggedIn] = useContext(username)

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("/posts")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
      setPosts(data)
      console.log(data)
      })   
    }, [])

      

if(loggedIn){
    return (
    <div align="center">
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <div>
      {posts.map(PostDisplay)}
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}

else{
    return (
        <div>
          <h1 align="center">You are not logged in!</h1>
        </div>
        )
}

}

export default Home
```

please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign a React component like that inside a map

```
{posts.map((post) => <PostDisplay post={post}/>)}
```

iterate through the array and pass the value as prop to the component.

```
const PostDisplay = ({post}) => {

  const [try, setTry] = useState("")

  return (
    <div>Hello </div>
  );


}
```